# Python multiprocessing.Process() not working inside Qt class

Tags: linux, qt, python-3.x, pyqt4, python-multiprocessing

I'm failing to start a `multiprocessing.Process()` instance inside a custom Qt Gui class. You can check the entire file (and the other files) from the project [here](https://github.com/allg18/MuonAquisitionTool/blob/master/main.py).

However, when I create it outside of the class, in the main file, it works. 
I have no idea why it behaves differently for those two ways.
(I don't know if it is relevant, but I'm running this program on a BeagleboneBlack, through "ssh -X", which shows the GUI windows on my computer. (I have to do this because one of the program's libraries can only run in the Beaglebone, because its GPIO interaction library).

Code inside the class (in the **init**() method) (this does not work, the GUI doesn't show up):

```
class MainWindow2(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow2, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent, self.child = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self.listener1=Listener(self.child)
        self.listening_proc=multiprocessing.Process(target=listener1)
        self.listening_proc.start()
```

Outside the class (this works):

```
parent, child = multiprocessing.Pipe()
listener1=Listener(child)
listening_proc=multiprocessing.Process(target=listener1)
listening_proc.start()
```